# How can I understand the subspace topology of a non-open subset of topological space X?

Tags: general-topology

Consider the topological space $X$ with subset $A \subseteq X$. Apparently I can construct a subspace topology on an arbitrary subset $A$, meaning the following is possible:

Given $X = \mathbb{R}$, and $A = [0, 1)$, we can clearly see that $A$ is not open under the neighborhood topology on $\mathbb{R}$. My current understanding of an "open set" is that it should be a neighborhood to each of its points. So if $A = \mathsf{Int}\ A$ (equal to its interior), then (and only then) is it an open set. But $\mathsf{Int}\ A = (0, 1) \ \neq [0,1) $.

And yet I have been told that if I construct a subspace topology with $A$, suddenly it is considered an open set, despite not being a neighborhood to each of its points? This feels like the meaning of "open" is somewhat lost, but I would love to understand how to think about this better; thank you!

**Edit**

Do note that $\mathsf{Int}\ A$ depends upon the context of the enclosing topological space to determine. For the given set $A$ inside of $\mathbb{R}$, the interior is the open set $(0, 1)$. But as commenter @fish points out, the interior to $A$ *inside the topological space* $A = [0, 1)$ is $\mathsf{Int}\ A = [0, 1)$.

Comment: Think about $\mathbb R\subset\mathbb R^2$. The subspace topology on $\mathbb R$ is in fact, the normal topology, but any open subset of $\mathbb R$ is clearly not one of $\mathbb R^2$? Why are you still comfortable with this? Most likely, it's because that within the domain of $\mathbb R$, the subspace topology's open sets, are open.

Comment: @DonThousand: That’s a somewhat problematic example, since technically $\Bbb R$ isn’t a subset of $\Bbb R^2$ in the first place.

Comment: Brian M. Scott has a detailed answer, but to comment on a specific statement you made: the interior of [0,1), considered as a subset of [0,1), is in fact [0,1) and not (0,1). So there is no contradiction.

Comment: Thank you fish! That completely makes sense to me. I am starting to see more and more how these topological concepts get their meaning from the context of what 
 topological space we are considering these properties under. To ask what the "interior" of a set is requires we have an answer to: "interior to what?"

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes, but there are many standard embeddings.

Comment: @DonThousand: The fact remains that $\Bbb R\times\{0\}\ne\Bbb R$,  and I really don't think it a good idea, paedagogically, speaking, either to obscure the distinction unnecessarily or to get bogged down in an explanation of implicit identifications and abuse of language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have to realize is that openness in topology isn’t an absolute concept. A non-empty set is never inherently open: it is open **in a particular topological space**. In your example, for instance, $[0,1)$ is not open in the space $\langle\Bbb R,\mathscr{E}\rangle$, where $\mathscr{E}$ is the usual Euclidean topology on $\Bbb R$. It **is** open, however, in the space $\big\langle[0,1),\mathscr{E}_{[0,1)}\big\rangle$, where

$$\mathscr{E}_{[0,1)}=\{U\cap[0,1):U\in\mathscr{E}\}$$

is the subspace topology that $[0,1)$ inherits from $\mathscr{E}$. It is also open in the [Sorgenfrey line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_limit_topology), the space $\langle\Bbb R,\sigma\rangle$, where $\sigma$ is the topology on $\Bbb R$ generated by the base

$$\{[a,b):a,b\in\Bbb R\text{ and }a<b\}\;.$$

And it is open in the space $\langle\Bbb R,\wp(\Bbb R)\rangle$, which is $\Bbb R$ with the discrete topology, in which **every** subset of $\Bbb R$ is open.

On the other hand, $[0,1)$ is **not** open in the subspace $\big\langle(-1,1),\mathscr{E}_{(-1,1)}\big\rangle$ of the real line with its usual topology. It is not open in $\big\langle\Bbb R,\{\varnothing,\Bbb R\}\big\rangle$, the real line with the indiscrete topology, whose only open sets are $\varnothing$ and $\Bbb R$ itself.

Comment: Thank you Brian. I can see how important it is to remember that "open" always carries around the implicit context of open to *some* topological space. When we consider the topological space on all of the points $[0, 1)$, I can see how we would make $[0, 1)$ itself closed and open within that space: the behavior of points at the "edge" of the entire space of consideration leaves room for interpretation of what it means to have a neighborhood around, say, $0 \in [0, 1)$, if there are literally no points outside of it in our space. So making $A$ clopen gives a convenient interpretation to that.

Comment: @NicholasMontaño: You’re welcome.